# How to create hyperlink within document using Aspose word report in java

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

Please help me to create Hyperlink With in Document using Aspose word report in Java

Answer (score 2):

You can meet this requirement by using any of the following [Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/products/words/java) codes:

Method # 1:

```
Document doc = new Document(getMyDir() + "in.docx");
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
builder.insertHyperlink("Aspose", "http://www.aspose.com/", false);
doc.save(getMyDir() + "awjava-16.4.0.docx");
```

Method # 2:

```
Document doc = new Document(getMyDir() + "in.docx");
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

// Get paragraph you want to append this Hyperlink to
Paragraph para = (Paragraph)doc.getChildNodes(NodeType.PARAGRAPH, true).get(1);

// Move cursor to this paragraph
builder.moveTo(para);

// We want to insert a Hyperlink like this:
// { " HYPERLINK Test1 \\l Test2 \\m \\n \\o Test3 \\t Test4" }

// Create instance of FieldHyperlink class and lets build the above field code
FieldHyperlink field = (FieldHyperlink)builder.insertField(FieldType.FIELD_HYPERLINK, false);
// HYPERLINK Test1
field.setAddress("Test1");
// HYPERLINK Test1 \\l Test2
field.setSubAddress("Test2");
// HYPERLINK Test1 \\l Test2 \\m
field.isImageMap(true);
// HYPERLINK Test1 \\l Test2 \\m \\n
field.setOpenInNewWindow(true);
// HYPERLINK Test1 \\l Test2 \\m \\n \\o Test3
field.setScreenTip("Test3");
// HYPERLINK Test1 \\l Test2 \\m \\n \\o Test3 \\t Test4
field.setTarget("Test4");

doc.save(getMyDir() + "awjava-16.4.0.docx");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.